# Python Scrapy How to insert all dictionary items in SQL DB

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary, web-scraping, scrapy

> how to insert all tags in dictionary of tag in SQL database, please if you can describe how to add all dictionary items in sql database, fat thanks in advance

```
import sqlite3
class QuotesPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("myquotes.db")
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def create_table(self):
        self.curr.execute("""create table if not exists quotes_tb(
                        title text, 
                        author text, 
                        tag text
                        )""")

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.store_db(item)
        #print("Pipeline is : " + item['author'][0])
        return item
    def store_db(self, item):
        self.curr.execute(""" 
            insert into quotes_tb (title, author, tag) values (?,?,?)""",(
            item['title'][0],
            item['author'][0],
            item['tag'][0]
            ))
        self.conn.commit()
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Do you get an error?

Comment: sorry for confusing
it was about enabling piplines in the settings.py 
and  i got the point 
fat thanks for you to pay attention